# Name of Generating One Value at a Time in Sequence Generation vs Encoder Decoder

Tags: machine-learning

a question about machine learning, specifically recurrent models:
For machine translation recurrent neural networks show great promise, common here is an encoder-decoder architecture which takes a source sentence, reads it, and then based on a compressed representation outputs a target sentence.
In opposition to that, for sequence generation you can also output one symbol at a time (let's stick with characters), e.g. like the char-rnn. You condition your model to learn the next character based on the ones you have read, so the model can e.g. create h-e-l-l-o, one character at a time. How would you call this second approach, does it have a name?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure how this is called, but an example of 'learn the next character based on the ones you have read' would be a Markov chain.